# C++ Switch Statement - Giving player another chance to choice

Tags: c++, switch-statement, default

This is a block of code from a book I've been studying and trying to improve upon, but I'm having trouble finding a way to give the player another chance at selecting the difficulty after entering the default choice. This is a very simple console text-based game and when the player chooses an incorrect choice, the game doesn't allow the player to re-choose.

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
     cout << "Difficulty Levels\n\n";
     cout << "1 - Easy\n";
     cout << "2 - Normal\n";
     cout << "3 - Hard\n\n";

     int choice;
     cout << "Choice: ";
     cin >> choice;


     switch (choice)
     {
      case 1:
         cout << "You picked Easy\n";
         break;
     case 2:
         cout << "You picked Normal\n";
         break;
     case 3:
         cout << "You picked Hard\n";
         break;
     default:
         cout << "Your choice is invalid.\n";
     }

     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Does the book honestly use `_tmain`? Please please please replace it with `int main()`.

Comment: You may use a loop as `do {..} while (choice < 1 || choice > 3)`

Comment: So you need a loop? Probably in the next chapter in the book (just a guess).

Comment: No, the _tmain was just default code with Visual Studio.

Comment: I've tried the Do, While loop. I only get an infinite amount of "Your choice is invalid" being outputed when i enter a number other than 1 - 3.

Comment: You need to include the `cin >> choice` as part of the loop.

Comment: `system("pause")` - my eyes!

Comment: lol is there a better alternative Proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refactor the switch into a function, which can be called whenever the player wants to change their difficulty choice.

```
int choose()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "Difficulty Levels\n\n";
    cout << "1 - Easy\n";
    cout << "2 - Normal\n";
    cout << "3 - Hard\n\n";

    cout << "Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
     case 1:
        cout << "You picked Easy\n";
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "You picked Normal\n";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "You picked Hard\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Your choice is invalid.\n";
        choice = 0; //this will signal error
    }
    return choice;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int choice = 0;
    while(choice == 0){choice = choose();};  
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now whenever the player decides to change difficulty (maybe they enter a special letter) you can use choice = choose() to alter the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the input code in a `do-while`.

```
bool valid = true;

do
{
    cout << "Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "You picked Easy\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "You picked Normal\n";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "You picked Hard\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Your choice is invalid.\n";
            valid = false;
    }
} while(!valid);
```